# Splitting data into Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to read data from a text file using a Buffered Reader. I'm trying to split the data into two Arrays, one of them is a double and the other one is a string. Below is the text file content:

```
55.6
Scholtz
85.6
Brown
74.9
Alawi
45.2
Weis
68.0
Baird
55
Baynard
68.5
Mills
65.1
Gibb
80.7
Grovner
87.6
Weaver
74.8
Kennedy
83.5
Landry.
```

Basically I'm trying to take all the numbers and put it into the double array, and take all the names and put it into the string array. Any ideas?

Comment: First thing: Formatting.
Format your question to isolate the text file contents, is it all on one line, etc...
Secondly, where is your code attempt?

Comment: You could possibly get the entire string from the buffered reader and then use regex to parse out the digits and other data. Then take each set of data from the regex and split them into their respective arrays using `.split("")`

Comment: If it follows this pattern 100% of the time, alternate the arrays you're casting to, first do the double[] then do the String[]
For a more concrete solution use @ParkerStromberg solution

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly get the entire string from the buffered reader and then use regex to parse out the digits and other data. A regex like `\d+\.*\d` should work to parse out the digits. And then a regex like `[A-Za-z]+` should get all of the names. Then take each set of data from the regular expressions and split them into their respective arrays using `.split("")`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String file = "path to file";
        double dArr[] = new double[100];
        String sArr[] = new String[100];
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([0-9]*)\\.[0-9]*"); // should start with any number of 0-9 then "." and then any number of 0-9 
            Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
            if (m.matches()) {
                dArr[i] = Double.parseDouble(line);
                i++;
            } else {
                sArr[j] = line;
                j++;
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

***Suggestion:*** Try `List` instead of array if uncertain about number of elements

`55` is treated as String as it is `int`

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this. I keep on getting an exception called "NullPointerException". I checked to make sure that there were no empty spaces in the text file; and there is none. what should I do?

Comment: @Asheer where are you getting the error? pls share the code and error trace by editing on your question.